# Mutually exclusive groups of arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a single Python file which includes unit tests in the source code. It works like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--test', action='store_true', help="Run unit tests and return.")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.test:
    testsuite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SanitizeTestCase)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(testsuite)
```

If `args.test` is false, the program runs as expected. I don't want to have to make this into an entire `setuptools` project, it's a pretty simple script with some unit tests to evaluate that it does what it's supposed to.

I now find myself needing to parse other arguments, and that's where things start to fall apart. `--test` is a mutually exclusive parameter and all of the other parameters don't apply if `--test` is passed.

Is there a way to have mutually-exclusive argument groups in argparse?

Comment: Have you looked at [mutually exclusive groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion)?

Comment: `setuptools` projects *do* have the advantage that they can be installed (and uninstalled) by pip.

Comment: Are these other arguments mutually exclusive to each other?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `mutually exclusive group` mechanism, but all the arguments in that group are mutually exclusive.  You can't say, `--test` xor any of the other others.

But such a group doesn't do anything profound.  It adds some markings to the `usage` line (try it), and it complains when your user (yourself?) violates the exclusivity.

You can do the same things yourself, and fine tune them.  You can give the `parser` a custom `usage` line.  And after parsing you can choose to ignore conflicting values, or you can choose to raise your own error message (`parser.error('dumb user, cant you read ...?')`).  You could, for example, ignore all the other arguments, regardless of value, if this `args.test` is `True`.